# Over 10K commits on my Visual Studio Source Control

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

For some reason I have over 10k commits within my VS code source code. This is something that is getting in the way of me uploading further projects to GitHub. I continue to receive the same error output: "Git warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied".

I've only tried staging the commits yet it continues to give me the same error.(Have read other posts yet no solution has ACTUALLY been found!) I've even created a new branch within my Git to store my project and this is still taking place.

Comment: What about in the terminal? What does git log (or reflog) say, and can you git push from there?